Algo anda mal: Error exception Undefined variable $juegos
Avanzando a trompicones en la programación, unas cosas salen y otras no, y llevo unas horas dandole vueltas a si es de una manera o de otra forma, el fragmento de código que genera este error es un formulario:
<form action="{{ route('storePartida') }}" method="POST">
  @csrf
  <input type="number" placeholder="Código" name="codigo">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre" name="nombre">
  <input type="date" placeholder="Fecha" name="fecha"
  <option value="option_select" disabled selected>Juego</option>
  <select name="juego_id" id="">
  @foreach ($juegos as $juego)
   <option value=" {{ $juego->id }} ">{{ $juego->nombre }}</option>
  @endforeach
  </select>
  <input type="number" placeholder="Jugadores" name="jugadores_partida">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Comentarios" name="comentario">
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>

Este es el fragmento del código del controlador:
public function storePartida(Request $request){
    $partida = new Partida;
    $partida -> codigo = $request -> codigo;
    $partida -> nombre = $request -> nombre;
    $partida -> fecha = $request -> fecha;
    $partida  = Partida::with(juegos) -> get();
    $partida -> jugadores_partida = $request -> jugadores_partida;
    $partida -> comentario = $request -> comentario;
    $partida -> save();
}

No se si incluir las relaciones de los modelos, por si acaso me equivocara en algo ahí, que no creo pero seguro ya no estoy de nada.....
Esto es la relación que hay en el modelo:
public function juego(){
    return $this->hasOne(App\Models\Juego::class, 'id', 'juego_id');
}

Pretendo tomar los valores de la tabla "juegos" en concreto el id, y usarlo para que me rellene un desplegable con los nombres que haya para generar una partida.
Edito la parte que modifique del controlador:
public function create(){
    $juegos=Juego::all();
    return view("create", compact('juegos'));
}

Con esto ya pasa la variable que no estaba definida, y ahora queda averiguar otra cosilla, seguiré experimentando.

¿Y cuál es el error completo?

El error dice que existe una variable llamada $variable que no está definida, pero el código compartido no tiene ninguna referencia a $variable. ¿Seguro que el código compartido es el que causa el error?

Cambie el nombre de la variable, es $juegos, ya la cambie para que no haya confusión

El error lo da en la linea "35" de mi código, que en el fragmento es el @foreach ($juegos as $juego)

Pues tal como dices, si.. estás intentando usar la variable $juegos pero no la has definido en ningún lugar. Qué esperas que tenga como valor??

Se supone que viene de una relación del modelo, pero, seguro no estoy, ya que como dije, cambie el código muchas veces y como esta fue el ultimo cambio

La acción del controller que has puesto solo hace el almacenamiento, no responde a la plantilla de ese formulario. Puedes añadir la acción del controller que llama a esa plantilla? Parece que en esa acción del controlador no defines la variable juegos para que lo use la plantilla.

Gracias por el comentario, probare eso, que ya no se si lo hice antes o no...por probarlo no pierdo nada

Edito el código como quedó, ya logro que muestre el desplegable, ahora me queda que al entrar al formulario no este seleccionado ninguno.

Solucionado, pongo la solución.

La solución fue modificar la función create quedando así:
public function create(){
    $juegos=Juego::all();
    return view("create", compact('juegos'));
}

Antes estaba con solo el return "simple":
public function create(){
    return view("create");
}

Con esta adición el problema de que no estaba la variable definida, se soluciona, pues ahora si se la mando.
